# matlab crashes when logged in via emacs

Tags: init-file, matlab

I have installed matlab-mode from the melpa repository. However when I do

```
M-x: matlab-shell [RET]
```

It gives me the following error.

```
objc[4164]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both
```

/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/sys/java/jre/maci64/jre/bin/java and
/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/sys/java/jre/maci64/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined

```
M-shell segmentation fault 11
```

Can anyone help me with this?.

Comment: If Emacs crashes there is a bug somewhere. Can you reproduce the problem starting with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the cause/culprit. You can use `comment-region` to comment out (or uncomment, with `C-u`) selected text. If you can give a reproducible recipe starting from `emacs -Q`, please file a bug report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Hi emacs doesn't crash, matlab does. I can run matlab in my terminal as usual but not in emacs. Not even using the terminal emulator inside emacs.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question (e.g. title) to make clear that it is not function `matlab-shell` (which is Emacs) that crashes. Also, what is `M-shell`? (The question is not yet clear to me, but hopefully it is clear to someone who is familiar with MatLab.)

Comment: I don't know what M -shell is. It is in the error thrown when it crashes. Apparently other people who use matlab-mode have run into this problem in MATLAB_R2016b. So it might be a bug in MATLAB. But then again I can run MATLAB from my terminal just fine.

Comment: OK, thanks. Hopefully someone else can shed some light on this and provide a useful answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly, this is a bug in MATLAB R2016b. A solution is to downgrade to R2016a!

I installed R2016b to find out that MATLAB crashes upon start up. What is strange however, is that I managed to run R2016b from Emacs once. My first thought was a bad configuration, but it kept crashing despite having cleared the config from `~/Library/Application\ Support/MathWorks/MATLAB/` (which is the new configuration path for R2016b).

It's difficult to point fingers from the stack trace (not knowing the source code), but around a "Run Path Dependent Initialization" is where mine crashes.

I have reported the segmentation fault to MathWorks (with a link to this question).

Comment: I reported the same to MATLAB many months ago. They either don't want or don't know how to fix it. The problem remains the same. So much for commercial software.

Comment: I just installed R2017a and the issue seems to be gone.